# Como saber qual objeto está com o foco em tempo de execução

Tags: delphi, delphi-10, delphi-berlin, delphi-tokyo, delphi-seatle

Vi que já tem um pergunta ***parecida*** com a minha só que é em **C#**.

Estou a fazer uma rotina de verificação de campo e quando um dos campos de data está em branco ele dá a mensagem. Preciso que quando um desses campos estiver com o foco, mostre o nome do campo no corpo da mensagem.

Códgo:

```
if (cbbTipoConsultaEmAberto.ItemIndex   = 5) and
   ((dteDataInicial.Text = '  /  /    ') or
    (dteDataFinal.Text    = '  /  /    ')) then
begin
  if (dteDataInicial.Text = '  /  /    ') then dteDataInicial.SetFocus else
  if (dteDataFinal.Text   = '  /  /    ') then dteDataFinal.SetFocus;
  Application.MessageBox(PChar('Combinação de Seleção Inválida!'+#13+'Campo: 
  '+TDBDateEdit({aqui tenho que saber qual o objeto com o foco}).Hint+
  ' está em branco.'),'Aviso',MB_OK+MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
  exit;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No formulário você consegue retornar o campo que esta ativo com a propriedade `ActiveControl`, no seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
if (cbbTipoConsultaEmAberto.ItemIndex   = 5) and
   ((dteDataInicial.Text = '  /  /    ') or
    (dteDataFinal.Text    = '  /  /    ')) then
begin
  if (dteDataInicial.Text = '  /  /    ') then dteDataInicial.SetFocus else
  if (dteDataFinal.Text   = '  /  /    ') then dteDataFinal.SetFocus;
  Application.MessageBox(PChar('Combinação de Seleção Inválida!'+#13+'Campo: 
  '+TDBDateEdit(Self.ActiveControl).Hint+
  ' está em branco.'),'Aviso',MB_OK+MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
  exit;
end;
```

Comment: Assim da 'access violation'

Comment: Consegui....retirei o .Name e funcionou... ficou assim `...TDBDateEdit(Self.ActiveControl).Hint...`

Comment: Apliquei a correção na resposta.